# Form not submitting input on pressing submit buttom

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I don't have much experience in PHP and js but I wanted a multiple-step form and found a free sample one online I thought I could customize and use however the submit button will not take me to the action page. I have tried troubleshooting and I found that if I delete a script (The 4th last line in the html) `<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-A-Modern-Multi-Step-Form-with-jQuery-CSS3/js/jquery.easing.min.js">` then the form works perfect however the style is messed. when I return it the form is looking good again but it won't submit. I would like the form to sumbmit and remain with the style as it is. This is my first time posting I hope I have followed guidlines and my question is understandable. Thansk in advance

```js
$(function() {

var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; 
var left, opacity, scale; 
var animating; 
$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
    next_fs.show(); 
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 1000, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
    previous_fs.show(); 
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 1000, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})

});
```

```css
   @import url(http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  font-family: Raleway;
}

h3{
  color: #002e6d;
  font-size:18px;
  line-height:28.8px; 
  font-weight:700;
  margin:0px 0px 30px;
}
#title {
  color: #002e6d;
  font-size:18px;
  line-height:28.8px; 
  font-weight:700;
  margin:0px 0px 30px;  
}

#msform{
  width: 85%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative; 
}

#msform fieldset{
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  position: absolute;
}
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type){
  display: none;
}

#msform fieldset{
  text-align: left;
}
#msform textarea{
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Raleway;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#msform input{
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Raleway;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 13px;
}


#msform .action-button{
  width: 100px;
  background: #002e6d;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #002e6d;
}
.fs-title{
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2C3E50;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight:500;
}
.fs-subtitle{
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#progressbar {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #D2D2D2;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#progressbar li.active {
    color: #002e6d;
}
#progressbar li:before{
    content:'' ;/*counter(step)*/
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#fff ;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 5px auto;    
  border: 2px solid #ECECEC;
}
#progressbar li:nth-child(1):before{
  content:"\f129" ;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #002e6d; 
}
#progressbar li:nth-child(2):before{
  content:"\f015" ;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #80858a;
  border: 2px solid #80858a;  
}
#progressbar li:nth-child(3):before{
  content:"\f007" ;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #80858a;
  border: 2px solid #80858a;    
}
#progressbar li:nth-child(4):before{
  content:"\f15c" ;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #80858a;
  border: 2px solid #80858a;    
}
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 73%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #ECECEC;
    position: absolute;
    left: -35%;
    top: 25px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
#progressbar li.active:before {
    border: 2px solid #002e6d;
    color: white;
    background-color:#002e6d;
  /* content: "\f164";*/
}
#progressbar li.active:after {
  background: #002e6d;
  color: white;
}
.form_holder {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">



</head>
<body>
<div class="form_holder">
<h2 class="fs-title" style="color: red;">MULTISPTEP FORM</h2>
<hr>

<form id="msform" action="page2.php" method="POST">

  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">step1</li>
    <li>step2</li>
    <li>step3</li>
    <li>step4</li>
  </ul>
  <fieldset>
    <h3>SOME HEADER</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <h2 class="fs-title" id="title">First</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 1 of 4</h3>

    <input type="password" name="1" placeholder="input1" required="" />
    <input type="password" name="2" placeholder="input2" required="" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Second</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 2 of 4</h3>
    <input type="text" name="3" placeholder="input3" required="" />
    <input type="text" name="4" placeholder="input4" required="" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Third</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 3 of 4</h3>
    <input type="text" name="5" placeholder="input5" required="" />
    <input type="text" name="6" placeholder="input6" required="" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Fourth</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Step 4 OF 4</h3>
    <input type="text" name=7 placeholder="input7" required="" />
    <input type="text" name="8" placeholder="input8" required="" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <!--input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />-->
    <button type="submit" class="submit action-button">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-A-Modern-Multi-Step-Form-with-jQuery-CSS3/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script  src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how are you hosting your files?

Comment: Well this line here
```js
$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
```
removes the submit functionality for each submit button that has the "submit" class on it, as it returns false. You should either remove that part of the script or trigger your submit functionality manually.

Comment: You are returning `false` when the submit button is clicked.  Why?  If I remove that part of the code snippet (remove that click handler entirely) then the form appears to post as expected.

Comment: Also, this question has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: @DanielD thanks for the answer. Allow me to ask kindly how to trigger it manually or from where to where I should remove it. I know this is like making you do the work. I am new to javascript

Comment: @David. Allow me to kindly ask what I should remove. I have deleted 
$(".submit").click(function(){
 return false;
})
   from the js and still it wont submit

Comment: @otejiri the files are still in my desktop. Im using XAMPP, its a local site still

Comment: @McChris_Made_It: Can you update the question to include that change?  When I edit your code snippet directly in the question above and remove that click handler, the form submits.  Granted, from the code snippet it of course gets a 404 when the form posts, but that's not what you're describing.  The form also appears to have required fields, in your test are you entering data in those fields?

Comment: @McChris_Made_It you can manually trigger form submits with the code provided by flakerimi's answer `$("#msform").submit();` But usually this isn't required if you use a submit button (type=submit) inside your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, doing .submit() triggers the submit function in the regular way. Instead you should do

```
$('#msform').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault() // to bypass the page refresh
    console.info($(this).serialize()); // to see what you're posting / if anything
    // do ajax or anything else you want here, just remember that $(this) references the form
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not sending form, just telling do nothing.

```
$(".submit").click(function(){   
//do anything else before submit
  //here
//then just submit
    $("#msform").submit();

})
```